# How to delete from device(s) all pictures already deleted in google photo?

Tags: photos, images

I always shoot lots of pictures, and then delete the "bad" ones.
I've been deleting them with Google Photo for years, assuming that the deleted files were deleted from the device memory too.  They are not.  Google photo does not show them nor keep them in the cloud, but all (good&bad) picture files are still there, in the device memory stick.

Deleting is hard work!  I don't wanna redo it again picture by picture...

I need an automatic way to tell Google Photo to identify all pictures previously deleted in the cloud, and delete them in my device(s) too.

Needless to say, google help does not help.
E.g. Google Photo has a button "Free up XXX MB" that does the opposite of what I want: it promises to purge all pictures that are already safely backed up in the cloud.  I.e. those I want to keep in my device too...!

The only way around I could figure out so far is to delete all pictures from my device(s), and then download the good ones back from the cloud.  This looks quite risky and cumbersome.  Anybody has a cooler idea how to proceed?